# javascript if function, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have written this javascript function but it doesn't seem to work. could someone tell me where i've gone wrong? it should be right, but after testing a bit, the generating a number bit seems to work, i think its the if statement which has a problem. any help would be appreciated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myfunction()
            {
                var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
                myfunc();
            }

            function myfunc()
            {
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    document.write("1")
                }
                else if (x == 2)
                {
                    document.write("2")
                }
                else if (x == 3)
                {
                    document.write("3")
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myfunction()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't call `document.write()`.

Comment: ive also tried alerting, still doesnt work

Comment: Are you not a fan of semicolons?...

Comment: You just need to pass the variable x into the function "myfunc" also, when developing I recommend using chrome DevTools https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/videos

Comment: Learn about variable scope. JavaScript 101.

Answer (score 7):

Pass x into your function like so..

```
var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
myFunc(x);

function myFunc(x) {
    //now you can use x
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`x` isn't in the scope of `myfunc`. It's in the scope of `myfunction`. You have to pass it as an argument:

```
myfunc(x);
```

And modify the definition of `myfunc`:

```
function myfunc(x)
```

Also, there's no need for the `if` statements. `document.write()` converts its argument to a string anyways, so you can just do:

```
function myfunc(x) {
    document.write(x);
}
```

Although if you're just testing stuff out, don't use `document.write`. Use `console.log` and open your JS console instead. It has code completion and works well with objects.

Comment: The reason I used an if statement is because I'm not actually going to be writing out the variable value. I used document.write to test the random number generator. I'm actually going to make it activate a different function depending on the value of x. Thanks for your answer this worked